# Does quitting putty close the running command

Tags: session, rsync, putty

I was using rsync to copy 15GB files between servers using putty.
I want to know that if i close putty terminal does that also termiates rync or not  because file is not copied properly.

I have tried that when i am doing backups then even if i close putty then scrip continue to run in background

Comment: This post provides step by step instructions to achieve it. https://pushprajsingh05.wordpress.com/2018/10/05/add-screen-to-your-linux-centos-machine

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Assuming your goal is to have the rsync command continue to run, the simplest thing is to orphan the job.  There are two ways to do this:

```
(rsync foo bar &)
```

The above will create the job detached from your terminal in the beginning, so closing the terminal will not stop it.

```
rsync foo bar & # or without &, then Ctrl-Z to stop, then "bg" to background
disown
```

The above will disown a running job, so you can close the terminal without stopping it.

Finally, you could use the program `screen(1)` or similar to keep a terminal session alive and intact (and able to be resumed) even when you end your Putty session.

Comment: I use PuTTY and putting `(echo "while True: __import__('time').sleep(1)" | python &)` into the console runs the Python process but exiting PuTTY still kills it.

Comment: Seems to be a limitation of the shared plan of my hosting-provider http://asmallorange.com

Comment: Closing Putty seems to close my background jobs, unless in screen. I might have to do some more experimentation.

Comment: @NateGlenn: try using `nohup` then.  It's one more way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Generally most command will quit if the console is closed.  If you want them to keep running look at the NOHUP command (Nohup is No Hang Up Process, a hang over from the days of modems and 'hanging up' the phone)

Answer (score 2):

I'd advocate performing long operations such as `rsync`ing 15GB across a network (or more pertinent to StackOverflow and programming, performing a large build on a remote host) within a [GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) session.

Then you can disconnect from the session (by closing PuTTY, if you like) and reconnect later to see how your job is progressing.

---

#### Update some time later...

These days I use and recommend [tmux](/questions/tagged/tmux) over [gnu-screen](/questions/tagged/gnu-screen).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running a rsync on some client the normal behaviour of a process is to terminate if it was loosing its controlling tty which is the case when you close putty. You may however run jobs with nohup (NOHUP(1)), and i guess that is what your backup scripts are doing (if no other "tricks" were involved). The output of your rsync commadn will then be appended to a file nohup.out in the current or your home directory depending on your permissions on the machine the nohup process is running on.

Answer (score 0):

**Reason:**

When you execute a Unix job in the background ( using &, bg command), and logout from the session, your process will get killed(Hang Up).

**Two solutions:**

1./ Nohup, which stands for no hang up, which can be executed as shown below.

nohup syntax:

```
# nohup command-with-options &
```

2./

```
(command-with-options &)
```